# Accordion control with nested items

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created accordion contol and in that accordion contol it has 2 radio button and button.I have created in HTML5 using javascrip and css in Dot net.When anyone of radio button is checked in same accordion panel some other controls panel should get open.And when another radio button is checked the panel of 1st radio button should get disable and another panel should be seen in same accordion control

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS alone, via the `:checked` pseudo-selector.

Example:

```
input[type="radio"] + div {
    height: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + div {
    height: 100px;
}
```

jsFiddle (complete with transitions): http://jsfiddle.net/dH65w/

Unfortunately transitions don't work right with `height: auto`, so you'd need fixed heights.  Also, the "+" part of the CSS doesn't work in IE7, and transitions don't even work in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery version of essentially the same thing as my other answer (more browser-compatible, but it's JavaScript).

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked + div').animate({
        height: "100px"
    }, ".25s");
    $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + div').animate({
        height: 0
    }, ".25s");
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dH65w/1/

The jQuery way is more flexible in that you can do things that wouldn't be allowed by the rules of CSS (such as affecting elements outside the parent element), as in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dH65w/2/